# How do I add a HttpContextAccessor to the Starup.cs in the correct way. (ASP.NET Core 6)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, httpcontext

So I'm trying to add a HttpContextAccessor to my startup.cs file and I find these two options.

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

So my question is, do I add both of them or just one?
And what is the difference between them?

Comment: They both [do the same thing](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Http/Http/src/HttpServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L26), stick with the second one for future-proofing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The call to AddHttpContextAccessor uses TryAddSingleton, which will register the service only if it hasn't already been registered.

services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

In your example, it has already been registered by that second call to services.AddHttpContextAccessor(), which means the next registration attempts do nothing.
```